# matlab Error: Input grid is an invalid Meshgrid

Tags: matlab

I want to interpolate an irregular 3-D grids using matlab command "interp3", what I
have is the coordinates of X,Y,Z and the values at each point. The dimension of x,y,z is 76*36*16 and the sampling positions stored in vectors x, y, and z are increasing.

[x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EobSw.jpg)
  [y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bG7Jh.jpg)
  [z](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNJ53.jpg)
[the values at each point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWlT4.jpg)
the commands I use to interpolate the grids are as belows:
`[x_out,y_out,z_out]=meshgrid(-310:5:310,-165:5:205,-70:5:5);`

```
vel_grid=interp3(x_3d,y_3d,z_3d,vel,x_out,y_out,z_out);
```

and the error message:
  your input grid is invalid Meshgrid.

I can't figure where is wrong about my input grids, the sampling positions stored in vectors x, y, and z are increasing. What conditions should my input grids still satisfy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your 3-D grids are irregular you cannot use `interp3` which supposes that your initial data is in a proper meshgrid order.

for example

```
x = rand(76,36,16);
y = rand(76,36,16);
z = rand(76,36,16);
v = rand(76,36,16);
slice(x,y,z,v,0,0,0);
```

will result in

```
Error using interp3 (line 147)
Input grid is not a valid MESHGRID.
Error in slice (line 104)
    vi = interp3(x,y,z,v,xi,yi,zi,method);
```

However you can use `scatteredInterpolant` as such

```
F =scatteredInterpolant(x_3d(:),y_3d(:),z_3d(:),vel(:)); 
[x_out,y_out,z_out]=meshgrid(-310:5:310,-165:5:205,-70:5:5);
v_out = F(x_out,y_out,z_out);
xslice = [0];
yslice = [0]; 
zslice = [,0];
slice(x_out,y_out,z_out,vel(:),xslice,yslice,zslice)
```

Comment: Thanks, the function of  'scatteredInterpolant' works. But as I know the interpolating method this function uses is Delaunay triangulation interpolation method. I wonder if this method is appropriate for my data.

Comment: You have to assess if your data can be structured into a grid. Don't hesitate to upvote if you liked

Comment: What do you mean by assessing if my data can be structured into a grid? My aim is undoubtedly interpolating my irregular points into regularly grid points. But as I am a green hand on determining which method such as bilinear or linear interpolation is applicable to my data. Can you give me some suggestion on how to judge if my data is fit to be structured into  a grid? Thanks.